# Empty object's physics tab is empty

Tags: physics

I would like to add rigid body constraints to empty objects, but the physics tab appears to be empty for some reason, any idea why this could be?

Comment: There also isn't a Force field or Soft Body option in the physics tab for other objects.

Comment: *"for other objects"* for which objects? And how is it related to your main question? Empty object can be either force field or Rigid Body constraint, that's all

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Empty objects have no geometry, what would you expect its the rigid body behavior to be?